# How to create Custom Fields in Activities in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

CRM :Suppose I have created a custom field in "Task" type activity.Now I want to show this custom field on Activity View. Is it possible ???

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that on Activity View as it's based on Activity Pointer which would only hold common attribute across all activity type. The only solution is change the view of task view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I know there is an Activity Pointer which refers the common fields from the all activities.But is there any solution in the back end of the CRM . Can we edit this Activity Pointer in the back end.

Comment: There is no supported way to do that. Can exist an unsupported way to do that.